# What does a ticket escalation e-mail look like?

Tags: communication, scrum

In many tutorials about issue tracking software and scrum based management a so called escalation process is mentioned. The idea is, that a first level agent sends an e-mail to a second level agent with the question to escalate a ticket.

To make things easier, I assume that the sender and receiver roles in the pipeline are correct and like to know how exactly such an e-mail would look like. I've tried to answer the question by myself by asking the wonderful global search engine but surprisingly, I didn't find a concrete example. Maybe the problem is too trivial for writing such an e-mail, but i'd like to improve my English skills so it would be nice if somebody could give a fictional example.

Comment: This is just too broad - providing example for each one case seems impossible.

Comment: It's correct that the question is hard to answer in general because no theory is available which formalizes scum on an academic basis. But exactly this is the reason why it make sense to analyze the problem in detail because the hope is to formalize the escalation process which allows to repeat the steps over and over again.

Comment: How formal is formal?  Every company is going to have its own answer to that question, and how they want to handle escalation of issues will likely depend heavily on how (or even if) they log issues in the first place.  It will depend on how big the company is, and how many people need to be in "the loop" on the issue.  It will also depend on what tools they're using, of which there are many to choose from.  There is no single, specific answer that will suit all comers.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. Issue (incident) tracking is very different from managing PBIs via a scrum based tool such as Jira. Also in my experience incidents almost always get escalated via phone call rather than email for immediacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to escalate a request then all you need to do is forward it to the next level, including a small blurb about why you're forwarding it.

> Hi [Second Level Team],
>   We have this issue [link to the issue]. We've done everything we can, and it's not resolved, can you investigate please?

If there are things you learned before you escalated, then make sure the second level team is aware of them when you forward it (hopefully this means recording them on the ticket, as Andrew Leach pointed out in the comments).

CC your manager and the second level team's manager, and if you're right that it's the second level team's responsibility then they will take it from there.

If it's *not* their responsibility then they will push it back to you, and they won't be happy about it. So be sure that it *is* their responsibility before you escalate. Get your manager's opinion if you're not sure.

Comment: Of course, things the Service Desk/First level have done to investigate the problem should be noted on the ticket so everything about the incident is kept in one place (just to make that point explicit).